# Incorrect type. Expected "string" in cloudformation yml file when editing in vscode

Tags: amazon-web-services, visual-studio-code, aws-cloudformation

[image]

how could I get rid of this warning in VS Code?

Comment: Please don't post images of code

Comment: Are you using Red Hat's `vscode-yaml` extension?

Comment: @PawelKam yes, I am using it. I tried to uninstall it, but it wouldn't allow me since Kubernetes plugin depends on it

Answer (score 3):

Unfortunately, it seems that *vscode-yaml* doesn’t support CloudFormation intrinsic functions out of the box.

One workaround is to disable YAML validation in your VSCode settings.

```json
  "yaml.validate": false
```

Another is to add `yaml.customTags` to your VSCode settings.

```json
  "yaml.customTags": [
    "!And scalar",
    "!And mapping",
    "!And sequence",
    "!If scalar",
    "!If mapping",
    "!If sequence",
    "!Not scalar",
    "!Not mapping",
    "!Not sequence",
    "!Equals scalar",
    "!Equals mapping",
    "!Equals sequence",
    "!Or scalar",
    "!Or mapping",
    "!Or sequence",
    "!FindInMap scalar",
    "!FindInMap mapping",
    "!FindInMap sequence",
    "!Base64 scalar",
    "!Base64 mapping",
    "!Base64 sequence",
    "!Cidr scalar",
    "!Cidr mapping",
    "!Cidr sequence",
    "!Ref scalar",
    "!Ref mapping",
    "!Ref sequence",
    "!Sub scalar",
    "!Sub mapping",
    "!Sub sequence",
    "!GetAtt scalar",
    "!GetAtt mapping",
    "!GetAtt sequence",
    "!GetAZs scalar",
    "!GetAZs mapping",
    "!GetAZs sequence",
    "!ImportValue scalar",
    "!ImportValue mapping",
    "!ImportValue sequence",
    "!Select scalar",
    "!Select mapping",
    "!Select sequence",
    "!Split scalar",
    "!Split mapping",
    "!Split sequence",
    "!Join scalar",
    "!Join mapping",
    "!Join sequence"
  ]
```

Read this thread for additional [information](https://github.com/redhat-developer/yaml-language-server/issues/77).

Also, note that AWS made a [*cfn-lint-visual-studio-code*](https://github.com/aws-cloudformation/cfn-lint-visual-studio-code) extension. I haven’t tried it, but apparently it added support to do this configuration automatically.

Quick read to resolve genuine template validation or format errors:
https://repost.aws/knowledge-center/cloudformation-template-validation.