# Visual Studio Code: YAML Validation Failing on CloudFormation Templates

Tags: amazon-web-services, visual-studio-code, aws-cloudformation

With the latest version of VSC and latest the RedHat YAML Extension, CloudFormation extension, and CFN-Lint extension, I still see `Incorrect Type: Expected String` for all the CFN Custom Tags.

I have all the correct custom tags defined in `settings.json` per [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75193446/incorrect-type-expected-string-in-cloudformation-yml-file-when-editing-in-vsc)

I can temporarily (for like a minute or two) work around it by disabling and re-enabling the YAML extension, but as soon as a legit error shows up (or when I'm typing and pause and it re-validates before I'm done with an attribute), the error is back. Has anyone else seen this? If so, how do you work around it?